# My if statement is not working.

Tags: java

i have below code and cant check if condition ... how can i solve it ?

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()); {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (null == arrayList || arrayList.size() == 0) {
            showToast("No data found from web!!!");
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        } else {
            Collections.sort(arrayList);
            setAdapterToListview(arrayList);
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't check if condition"? What's wrong? any errors?

Comment: What do you mean you can't check it?

Comment: Solve the **compiler errors** first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

remove `;` end of the first if condition

it should be 
`if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing());`  <<< Remove `;`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the semi colon `;` from the first line.
Instead of

```
if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing());
```

it should be

```
if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing())
```

with no semi colon at the end :)